# On the Second and Third Largest Prime Divisors of an Odd Perfect Number

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers

Over twenty years years ago, Douglas Iannucci proved that the second largest prime divisor of an OPN exceeds $10,000$.

See https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1999-68-228/S0025-5718-99-01126-6/S0025-5718-99-01126-6.pdf

(Incidentally, I believe that he also proved that the third largest prime divisor of an OPN exceeds $100$.)

Are these still the best known bounds to date or have either bound been increased?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, both bounds (proved by [Douglas E. Iannucci](https://www.mathgenealogy.org/id.php?id=26955)) have not been improved.

These facts are noted in two (recent) separate papers:

[Upper bounds on the second largest prime factor of an odd perfect number - by Joshua Zelinsky (2018) - page 2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.11734.pdf) - [Iannucci (1999)](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1999-68-228/S0025-5718-99-01126-6/S0025-5718-99-01126-6.pdf) proved that the second largest prime divisor of an odd perfect number exceeds $10000$.

[On the third largest prime divisor of an odd perfect number - by Sean Bibby, Pieter Vyncke, and Joshua Zelinsky (2019) - page 2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.09420.pdf) - [Iannucci (2000)](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2000-69-230/S0025-5718-99-01127-8/S0025-5718-99-01127-8.pdf) proved that the third largest prime divisor of an odd perfect number exceeds $100$.

At least one of the authors (Zelinsky) has an MSE account.

Comment: Thank you for this very informative answer.

Comment: You are welcome, @mlchristians.